# Brown and yellow orchid leave

Tags: plant-health

Help...my phalenopsus orchid bloomed and looked gorgeous. The blooms are now spent..and the top leaves have started to discolor. Can someone help my orchid???
[image][image]

Comment: While you wait, dont water the orchid.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest leaving your orchid in a bright window, out of direct light, and let her dry. If you were watering her once a week, or even every other, she's likely getting too wet.  When I lived in a very humid climate, I watered my orchids once every 4-6 weeks...they thrived on what others thought was neglect.  In drier climates, I water twice a month when it's hot, less when it's cold.  Check the roots -- in healthy roots: green is good, grayish needs water.  I would also suggest that when you do water her, soak her roots in water for a few minutes rather than giving her ice cubes. Those top leaves may fall off, just have patience :)

Comment: Thank you so much.. I have been just soaking them in my sink for 15 min once a week.. I will try to go to every 2 or 3 weeks and see how she does...